# jquery multiple checkbox issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add a multiple checkbox in a table.

and this is the code.

**HTML**

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <TITLE>Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect - DEMO</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <H2>Multiple Checkbox Select/Deselect - DEMO</H2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th><input type="checkbox" id="selectall"/></th>
    <th>Cell phone</th>
    <th>Rating</th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="1"/></td>
    <td>BlackBerry Bold 9650</td>
    <td>2/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="2"/></td>
    <td>Samsung Galaxy</td>
    <td>3.5/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="3"/></td>
    <td>Droid X</td>
    <td>4.5/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="4"/></td>
    <td>HTC Desire</td>
    <td>3/5</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" class="case" name="case" value="5"/></td>
    <td>Apple iPhone 4</td>
    <td>5/5</td>
</tr>
</table>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**jQuery**

```
<SCRIPT language="javascript">
$(function(){

    // add multiple select / deselect functionality
    $("#selectall").click(function () {
          $('.case').attr('checked', this.checked);
    });

    // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
    // and viceversa
    $(".case").click(function(){

        if($(".case").length == $(".case:checked").length) {
            $("#selectall").attr("checked", "checked");
        } else {
            $("#selectall").removeAttr("checked");
        }

    });
});
</SCRIPT>
```

OK this works fine, but the problem is, what i'm going to do is not a static table.

it request and response and appends the table dynamically.

and if the rows are added like this. it doesn't handle the event.

Any good idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

```
 // add multiple select / deselect functionality
 $("#selectall").click(function () {
     $('.case').prop('checked', this.checked);
 });

 // if all checkbox are selected, check the selectall checkbox
 // and viceversa
 $(document).on('click', ".case", function () {
     $("#selectall").prop("checked", $(".case:not(:checked)").length == 0);
 });
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mXdsk/)

Also use [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to set the checked state

Comment: yes i checked. if it is a static table. this code works. But in my situation this doesnt work

Comment: then there is some other issue

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I got the bug :)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery support event [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/), just like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.case', function(){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .on() function. Examples can founded in http://api.jquery.com/on/